# Date difference, two variables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem: I am writing a query to check if the date from a given column is 6 weeks from another column.

I have tried DATEDIFF for other date checks, but that has been with a fixed date as one of the variables. I have two different variables in this case.

My code attempt:

```sql
SELECT *
DATEDIFF(d, ifc_forecast, date_complete)
FROM ifc_file
ORDER BY
ifc_forecast DESC
```

Comment: "6 weeks" is a measure that can mean different things to different people. Provide a few, actual examples of your data and the results you expect. And is "d" more readable in your datediff usage than "day"? Think about that.

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired resultset. From what I understand try this. SELECT DATEDIFF(week, ifc_forecast, date_complete) FROM ifc_file

Comment: For starters, you're missing a comma      SELECT *, DATED...

Comment: @JohnCappelletti:no, it's just a bad formatted question, you may choose, bad formatted SQL , or bad formatted question....

Comment: @Luuk OP didn't provide the error, sample data or desired results.  The DATEDIFF() looks to be formatted correctly, my thought was they may be chasing ghosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be as simple as:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(wk, date1, date2) FROM table...
```

provided that your fields/variables are proper datetime columns.

Reference: [DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

But probably you'll get a more accurate result by counting the number of **days** instead, so:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, date1, date2) FROM table...
```

6 weeks = 42 days.